# In sklearn, is there a way to get access to the .loss_curve_ attribute of an MLPClassifier after using GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to be able to plot the loss curves for each set of parameter combinations that was used within a run of fitting MLP models within GridSearchCV.

I am able to access the loss curve if I have a fixed set of parameters, eg:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

mlp_nickname = 'my_mlp'

def test(
    X_TV,
    y_TV,
    X_Test,
    y_Test,
    train_dict,
    random_state,
    ):

    # Initialize learner pipeline
    pipeline = Pipeline([])
    learner = MLPClassifier()
    learner.set_params(random_state=random_state)
    pipeline.steps.append((mlp_nickname, learner))
    
    # Set hard-coded parameters for this experiment
    pipeline.set_params(**hf.pipeline_helper(train_dict, mlp_nickname))

    # Test model
    final_model = pipeline.fit(X_TV, y_TV)
    plt.plot(final_model[mlp_nickname].loss_curve_) # This works!
```

However, if I do training through GridSearchCV, I am not seeing if/how to access the loss curve data

```
def train(
    X_TV,
    y_TV,
    train_dict,
    param_grid,
    random_state,
    ):

    # Initialize learner pipeline
    pipeline = Pipeline([])
    learner = MLPClassifier()
    learner.set_params(random_state=random_state)
    pipeline.steps.append((mlp_nickname, learner))
    
    # Set hard-coded parameters for this experiment
    pipeline.set_params(**hf.pipeline_helper(train_dict, mlp_nickname))

    # Fit
    print('\tGridSearch verbose:')
    grid = GridSearchCV(
        pipeline,
        param_grid,
        scoring = 'f1_weighted',
        n_jobs  = -1,
        refit   = True,
        cv      = 5,
        verbose = 1,
        return_train_score = False,
        )
    grid.fit(X=X_TV, y=y_TV)
```

At this stage, GridSearchCV works as expected and I am able to access the hyperparameters that perform the best. However, I also want to be able to view the loss curves from each run, is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I spent a bit of time looking into this, specifically using multiple metrics (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#using-multiple-metric-evaluation) as the 'scoring' argument to GridSearchCV. However, even though I was able to create the loss curve as a scoring function, GridSearchCV only accepts numbers, not lists, as scores. One option would be to hand code the GridSearchCV, here's an example: https://www.kaggle.com/code/nnjjpp/tracking-experiments-with-comet-com#Hand-coded-grid-parameter-search.

Comment: This is what I have been afraid of, ha! Not the worst thing in the world to have to build our own GridSearch procedure, but at least I'm hoping to know that I'm not wasting my time doing so and its not that there is a magical method out there that I am not seeing.

Comment: Yes, GSCV is probably not as customisable as we'd want. Maybe there is a magical method out there but it's not obvious, and to be honest it'll probably take less effort to hand-code the GSCV. :)